# Missing icons after migration of awstats

Tags: awstats

I migrated awstats from one server to another, and I copied the old stats and configuration. I had to change apache log directory but it seems it is working: http://permaculture.org.au/awstats/awstats.pl

The issue is that icons are missing and graphics do not have colours. The line in apache2 config

Alias /awstats-icon/ "/usr/share/awstats/icon/"

is okay since there are the icons in that directory:

root@server:/etc/awstats# ls -l /usr/share/awstats/icon/
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2011-11-03 13:34 browser
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2011-11-03 13:34 clock
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2011-11-03 13:34 cpu
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 12288 2011-11-03 13:34 flags
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2011-11-03 13:34 mime
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2011-11-03 13:34 os
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2011-11-03 13:34 other

last issue is that when I run awstats from the shell the script hangs here:

root@server:/etc/awstats# /usr/lib/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=awstats.permaculture.org.au.conf -update
Create/Update database for config "/etc/awstats/awstats.conf" by AWStats version 6.9 (build 1.925)
From data in log file "/var/log/apache2/access.log"...
Phase 1 : First bypass old records, searching new record...
Searching new records from beginning of log file...
Phase 2 : Now process new records (Flush history on disk after 20000 hosts)...
Reverse DNS lookup for ::1 not available without ipv6 plugin enabled.

Answer (score 2):

We have alias in apache config file:

```
Alias /awicon /usr/share/awstats/icon
```

Answer (score 0):

If the icons are missing on the web page. Check with your access.log for it would show you the images that are not found as `404` and you would know where is the webpage searching for the icons in and configure your alias as accordingly.

Secondly, disable IPv6 if you are not running/using it. ::1 is the ipv6 address for your localhost. Also you might be missing a few perl modules see [here](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_contrib.html#PLUGINS) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I have symlinked the icons from the configured virtual host root directory to the real directory where they were stored.